# Evaluate instance variable (defined in controller), from within a test.js.erb view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I evaluate an instance variable from within the javascript view (for use by another AJAX process)?

I would like do a conditional evaluation (in my test.js.erb file) of an instance variable defined in a controller method.

Controller method:

```
def test
  @var = 100
end
```

.JS View:

```
if (<%= @var=100 %>) {
  alert("var: " + <%= @var %>);
} else {
  alert("failed");
}
```

Do I need to build the entire conditional check within erb tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (<%= @var %> === 100 ) {...}
```